# Change Compiler VsCode

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, cmake

I am new in c++
The cmakelist.txt file dont give me a Makefile

```
-- Building for: Visual Studio 16 2019
-- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.19041.0 to target Windows 10.0.22000.
-- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.29.30140.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.29.30140.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/BuildTools/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.29.30133/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/BuildTools/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.29.30133/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/JohnSmith/Documents/Hello/build
```

I dont know how to change the compiler to G++
this is the cmake

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER "gcc")
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "g++")
project(HelLo)
add_executable(Hello main.cpp hello.cpp)
```

I am on windows , Thanks for help
(I can compile with g++ and gcc just cmakefile dont work )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make sure you've installed [gcc/g++ under Windows](https://gcc.gnu.org/install/binaries.html) (either CygWin or MinGW). Remove the set commands from your `CMakelists.txt`. Then in a CygWin/MinGW shell use the following command to generate the Makefile:

```
CC=gcc CXX=c++ cmake ..
```

Answer (score 0):

cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" ..